# Better Rendering with focus one position?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

At the moment, I do not have a powerful GPU to be even doing extensive 3D modeling, but oh well, I downloaded Blender and started making something anyway.

The problem is that Blender (with Cycles render engine) simultaneously renders two or three blocks. I thought maybe I can limit the block to just one, so that the internal graphics GPU can render that specific block to the specified sample value.

Comment: CPU rendering will render several tiles at the same time depending on the number of cores but gpu rendering will either render 1 tile at a time or the whole image.

Comment: Rendering multiple tiles at once means that blender is taking advantage of multiple CPU cores/GPUs to render more of the image faster. Is there some reason why you don't want this?

Comment: @gandalf3 Just making the rendered image less noisy, I guess.

Comment: @user2442110 Rendering multiple parts of the image at once should have no effect on the final result.. Each tile will be rendered for the specified number of samples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you would want this, as the end result will always be the same, but if it is just that you can see one part of the shot fully rendered than have a look at this:
[image]

**Tiles**
Under Performance you choose your tile-size which is the size of one block (in pixels). You can set it to start from whichever part of the image you like (where it says centre), so if you have something in your shot which you want to see first rendered to the fullest make sure you set it to start, wherever the item of interest is.

**Threads**
You can also set a fixed number of threads and put it to one this way you will always have one tile processing at a time (but that just doesn't use the full capacity of your machine, so i suggest leave it at auto).

**Progressive Refinement**
What, I assume, you don't want is the progressive refinement box ticked, that will cause it to use another algorithm, which will show you the whole picture very quickly, and as the name suggests will refine it progressively over time. So make sure this is un-ticked, for achieving what you want.

Comment: Whoa! Changing the threads to one actually works! Thanks!